# Tidy way to batch calls to Google Vision using purr and RoogleVision?

Tags: r, purrr, google-vision

I have a directory with images, and I'd like to query the Google Vision API for each and store the aggregate output in one tibble.

I tried what seemed like an easy solution: if `getGoogleVisionResponse("file1.png")` works, then all I need is:

```
files <- dir("image-path")
map(files, getGoogleVisionResponse)
```

Only to get: 
`Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection`

I found this answer, which involves writing a function from scratch, but that seems untidy and overkill, no?
[Create variable and dataset in a loop? (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155238/create-variable-and-dataset-in-a-loop-r)

I also found [this pull request](https://github.com/cloudyr/RoogleVision/pull/12) that aimed to address this, but it did not get merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dir` doesn't return the full path, so if you `dir` to get the contents of a folder you'll only get the file names:

```
> dir("mydir")
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```

Passing those to any function that requires a path will fail.

Instead if you use `full.names=TRUE` you get the full paths to the file:

```
> dir("mydir",full.names=TRUE)
[1] "mydir/a" "mydir/b" "mydir/c" "mydir/d" "mydir/e" "mydir/f" "mydir/g"
```

Comment: Wow, if that's all I'm missing... Can't check until tomorrow, but will report back. Thanks!